# wp warning declaration compatible

Tags: warnings

Good night.

Please help me.

Update WP to version 5.3 and you are now displaying this message on the WP website and admin (

> Warning: Declaration of kiddy_Walker_Nav_Menu::walk($items, $depth) should be compatible with Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth, ...$args) in /var/www/html/eeicurumim.com.br/web/wp-content/themes/kiddy/functions.php on line 3002

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Your themes `style.css` tells me you bought it at http://themeforest.net/user/creativews http://kiddy.cwsthemes.com/, you need to contact their support, this isn't a support forum for premium themes. 3rd party themes are offtopic

Answer (score 3):

Lets say that you're a cook, and I tell you in order to pass a test you have to make:

- 3 cakes
- 1 pie
- 7 cookies

And you come back to me with 4 cakes and a pie, those don't match, you failed the test.

The same thing is happening in your code:

> Warning: Declaration of kiddy_Walker_Nav_Menu::walk($items, $depth) should be compatible with Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth, ...$args) in /var/www/html/eeicurumim.com.br/web/wp-content/themes/kiddy/functions.php on line 3002

`kiddy_Walker_Nav_Menu` inherits from `Walker` but it has a mismatching incompatible function inside it.

---

So lets pick it apart, as it outright tells you what the problem is

> kiddy_Walker_Nav_Menu::walk($items, $depth) should be compatible with Walker::walk($elements, $max_depth, ...$args)

Here's the problem, notice the parameters don't match, they **must** match. `$items, $depth` and `$elements, $max_depth, ...$args` are not the same.

> in /var/www/html/eeicurumim.com.br/web/wp-content/themes/kiddy/functions.php on line 3002

Is just telling you which file the issue is in, and which line of the file it happens.

#### So how do you fix it?

You make them match. You need to accept 3 things, a set of items, a max depth, and some arguments. But your version doesn't do that, so start by adding `, ...$args`

Comment: Thanks Tom for the feedback, and sorry for entering my question in the wrong location. I don't know how to fix it yet, I identified the place

end_el function (& $ output, $ item, $ depth = 0, $ args = array ()) {
$ indent = ($ depth)? str_repeat ("\ t", $ depth): '';
$ logo_container = '';
if ($ item-> menu_item_parent == '0' and & $ this-> elements <$ this-> logo_in_menu_number && $ this-> elements == $ this-> elements_counter) {
$ logo_container = $ this-> logo_ini ($ indent, $ item);
}
$ output. = "</li> \ n". $ logo_container;
}

But I still don't know what to adjust / change

Comment: @AndersonCamargo I'm afraid you're going to need a minimum level of PHP understanding to fix this, the only alternative is to provide copy pasta which I won't do. **You should go to the support for the theme you bought**